# Find expectation and covariance of W= V^2/R? V and R have uniform distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

So I have $W$ = $\frac{V^2}{R}$

With $V$ ~ $U(10,20)$  and  $R$ ~ $U(1,2)$

Find the expectation $E(W)$ and covariance of $W$.

EDIT: Since covariance makes no sense here, I'm pretty sure deviation was asked instead.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that V and R are independent from each other, then
$E[W] = E[V^2]*E[\frac{1}{R}]$

To find $E[V^2]$ you can use $var(V)=E[V^2] - (E[V])^2$ and solve for $E[V^2]$. Since you know $V$ is uniform, you can find $var(V)$ and $(E[V])^2$ easily.

To find $E[\frac{1}{R}]$ use the general form of the expected value rule:
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)*f_X(x) dx$ where $g(x) = \frac{1}{R}$ and $f_X(x)$ is calculated from the given uniform distribution for $R$. The bounds on the integral get replaced by the upper and lower bounds for $R$.

To find covariance, you need to specify 2 random variables, not one. So $cov(W)$ is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure the problem asked deviation instead of covariance so I think I need to calculate E(W^2) in order to get var(W). Do you know how to get E(W^2)?

Comment: There could certainly be a better way to solve this, but my initial thought is that $E[W^2] = E[\frac{V^4}{R^2}]$. You can find that expected value by following a similar approach as before, using the general form of the expected value rule since $f_V(v)$ and $f_R(r)$ are easy to find since they are uniform. The algebra might get a bit messy. Then $var(W) = E[W^2]-(E[W])^2$. Again, this only works if V and R are independent. I'm assuming that they are. If they are not independent then you can't solve it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time